# Can every value be attained by determinant even if first row is fixed

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The following question  was asked in my linear algebra quiz and i had a hard time figuring it out .

> Question :
>
> State true or false - Let n$\geq$ be an integer . Given an integer k does there exists an  n * n matrix A with integer entries such that detA=k and the first row of A is (1,2,...,n)

I verified it for 2* 2 matrix and in that case it is true . I have an intution that this would be true for n* n matrix but i have no idea on how it can be proved .

Kindly shed some light on this.

Comment: If the first row is fixed, you can make everything but the diagonal 0 and then the determinant is simply the product of the diagonal entries (as it is upper diagonal). Thus you can choose 1 for every diagonal entry but the last which is $k$. Example: $$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 23\end{matrix} \right) $$has determinant $23$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume

$n \ge 2, \tag 1$

for with

$n = 1, \tag 2$

the only possibility for $A$ is the $1 \times 1$ matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag 3$

with

$\det A = 1. \tag 4$

Now accepting condition (1), we let $A$ be the $n \times n$ integer matrix whose first row is $(1, 2, \ldots, n)$, the diagonal of which has

$A_{nn} = k, \tag 5$

and

$A_{jj}  = 1, \; 2 \le j \le n - 1, \tag 6$

with every other entry of $A$ taken to be $0$; then expanding $\det A$ in minors along the first column yields

$\det A = 1 \cdot (1 \cdot 1 \cdot \ldots \cdot k) = k, \tag 7$

where there are $n - 2$ $1$s inside the parentheses, which as we can see is simply $A_{11}$ times the determinant of the $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$ matrix

$[A_{ij}], \; 2 \le i, j \le n. \tag 8$

This shows our matrix $A$ satisfies

$\det A = k, \tag 9$

$OE\Delta$.